# Symfony2 dynamic assetic in twig template

Tags: symfony, dynamic, twig, assetic

I'm trying show image using assetic (symfony2, twig). URL address of image depends on the bundle.

```
{% image '@'{{ bundleName }}'/Resources/public/images/logo.png' %}
   <img src="{{ asset_url }}" />
{% endimage %}
```

But it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the [concatenation operator](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/templates.html#other-operators) (`~`) to combine expressions inside twig tags:

```
{% image '@' ~ bundleName ~ '/Resources/public/images/logo.png' %}
```

Comment: Unexpected token "operator" of value "~" in ControlBundle:AdminArea:types.html.twig at line 62

Comment: @TroyashkA oh, seems like assetic isn't supporting this. I don't think this is possible, after looking at the code

Comment: Any way to get this working? Can you point me to the correct place in the code so I can work on a fix?

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround for this.  My situation is that I have images stored in a subdirectory under Resources/images.  I wanted them there, rather than the web directory, as they will only be used temporarily and I want to just delete the subdirectory when they are no longer needed rather than having to delete images from various subdirectories.  So, I couldn't use the asset() function (since the images were in the bundle) and assetic doesn't seem to support dynamic images.

I needed to display one of 2 banner images based on certain criteria. I wound up creating a twig template that would generate each image using assetic (2 images, so 2 templates).

```
<a href="{{ vm.bannerLinkUrl }}">
    {% image '@MyBundle/Resources/public/images/path/to/image/banner.jpg' %}
    <img src="{{ asset_url }}">
    {% endimage %}
</a>
```

I created a 'banner' action in my Home controller to render the templates.

```
public function bannerAction()
{
    /* code to load data into a view model object called $vm */

    $template = $this->render(
        "MyBundle:Home:path/to/banner-template-subdir/{$vm->bannerType}-banner.html.twig",
        ['vm' => $vm]
    );

    return $template;
}
```

Finally, I used the render function to generate the correct banner from the main page template.

```
<div class='banner'>
    {{ render(controller("MyBundle:Home:banner")) }}
</div>
```